# Android Setting Alarm from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

Having real issues setting a repeating alarm using AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver from within a Fragment. Have no problem with the following code from within an Activity. When moved to a Fragment the BroadcastReceiver never calls onReceive.

Fragment:

```
public void startAlarm(View view) {

    Log.i(TAG, "startAlarm");

    mAlarmMgr     = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    mAlarmIntent  = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, intent, 0);

    mAlarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                           SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
                           60 * 1000,
                           mAlarmIntent);
}

public void cancelAlarm(View view) {

    Log.i(TAG, "cancelAlarm");

    // If the alarm has been set, cancel it.
    if (mAlarmMgr!= null) {
        mAlarmMgr.cancel(mAlarmIntent);
    }
}
```

Alarm:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = AlarmReceiver.class.getName();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.i(TAG, "onReceive");

    // For our recurring task, we'll just display a message
    Toast.makeText(context, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}}
```

Manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name=".alarms.AlarmReceiver">
    </receiver>
```

Just curious where I may be going wrong? I'm thinking that perhaps I'm not registering the Receiver correctly in the Manifest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this,
start alaram

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Services.class);
Services.shouldContinue=true;
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
pintent = PendingIntent.getService(getActivity(), 0, intent, 0);
alarm = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
if (Services.shouldContinue) {
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(), 5 * 1000, pintent);           
 }
```

cancel alaram

```
   Services.shouldContinue = false;
    if (intent != null) {
        getActivity().stopService(intent);
    }

    alarm.cancel(pintent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your receiver definition to below

```
<receiver android:name=".alarms.AlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
```

Make sure you are calling `startAlarm(View view)`to initialize alarm.

Comment: `receiver` elements are `enabled=true` by default so that's redundant.  Also you should not be exporting your `BroadcastReceiver` unless you intend to have other apps on the device call your receiver.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this as well as using the full package name for android:name. Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is something more like this

```
private setRepeatingAlarm(Context context) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent  = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    long interval = 60 * 1000;
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
}
```

The main difference here is using `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP` vs `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP`.

One thing you should watch out for in 5.0+ the min interval for an alarm is 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks. Tried this approach as well and have tried both inexact and interval repeating. Have tried both RTC_WAKEUP and ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP and longer and shorter intervals. Still no luck. Like I mentioned above all the code works when called from an Activity as expected. When I move the start and cancel methods to a Fragment the methods get called but no alarm is set.